# Function's return type missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to plot a d3.js force graph using react and type script.

When I am importing a function so I am getting error:
TS2786: 'NetPlot' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type '{ destroy: () => void; nodes: () => SVGSVGElement | null; }' is not a valid JSX element.
Type '{ destroy: () => void; nodes: () => SVGSVGElement | null; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

I checked and changed many parts of codes but couldnot solve the problem.

My code for "cluster_intercon.tsx":

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import MainLayout from "../../layout/main_layout";
import CurrentACCI from "./current_ac_ci/current_ac_ci";
import {NetPlot} from "./plots/net_graph";


export default function ClusterIntercon() {
    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <Helmet>
                <title>
                    Inventia AI - Research Clustering & Interconnections
                </title>
            </Helmet>
            <div
                className="
        flex flex-row
        h-full
        "
            >
                {/* Plot area */}
                <div className="w-3/4 mt-4 mb-1 mx-4 flex flex-col">
                    <h2 className="text-2xl">
                        Research Clustering & Interconnections
                    </h2>
                    {/* Plot */}
                    <div className="h-3/4">
                        
                        <NetPlot></NetPlot>
                    </div>
                    {/* Selected Articles */}
                    <div className="flex flex-row h-1/4">
                        <p className="text-md">Selected</p>
                        <div className="w-5/12 h-full ml-10 mr-auto overflow-y-scroll">
                            <div className="card my-2 mx-3 fade-in-left">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <div className="card-title text-primary">
                                        <a
                                            target="_blank"
                                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                        >
                                            Title
                                        </a>
                                        <svg
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                            x="0px"
                                            y="0px"
                                            width="20"
                                            height="20"
                                            viewBox="0 0 30 30"
                                            style={{ fill: "#F59E0B" }}
                                        >
                                            <path d="M 25.980469 2.9902344 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 25.869141 3 L 20 3 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 20 5 L 23.585938 5 L 13.292969 15.292969 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 14.707031 16.707031 L 25 6.4140625 L 25 10 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 27 10 L 27 4.1269531 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 25.980469 2.9902344 z M 6 7 C 4.9069372 7 4 7.9069372 4 9 L 4 24 C 4 25.093063 4.9069372 26 6 26 L 21 26 C 22.093063 26 23 25.093063 23 24 L 23 14 L 23 11.421875 L 21 13.421875 L 21 16 L 21 24 L 6 24 L 6 9 L 14 9 L 16 9 L 16.578125 9 L 18.578125 7 L 16 7 L 14 7 L 6 7 z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <p className="text-md">Abstract</p>
                                    <div className="card-actions justify-end">
                                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-error">
                                            Remove
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p className="text-md">Connected</p>
                        <div className="w-5/12 h-full mr-5 overflow-y-scroll">
                            <div className="card my-2 mx-3 fade-in-left">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <div className="card-title text-primary">
                                        <a
                                            target="_blank"
                                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                        >
                                            Title
                                        </a>
                                        <svg
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                            x="0px"
                                            y="0px"
                                            width="20"
                                            height="20"
                                            viewBox="0 0 30 30"
                                            style={{ fill: "#F59E0B" }}
                                        >
                                            <path d="M 25.980469 2.9902344 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 25.869141 3 L 20 3 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 20 5 L 23.585938 5 L 13.292969 15.292969 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 14.707031 16.707031 L 25 6.4140625 L 25 10 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 27 10 L 27 4.1269531 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 25.980469 2.9902344 z M 6 7 C 4.9069372 7 4 7.9069372 4 9 L 4 24 C 4 25.093063 4.9069372 26 6 26 L 21 26 C 22.093063 26 23 25.093063 23 24 L 23 14 L 23 11.421875 L 21 13.421875 L 21 16 L 21 24 L 6 24 L 6 9 L 14 9 L 16 9 L 16.578125 9 L 18.578125 7 L 16 7 L 14 7 L 6 7 z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <p className="text-md">Abstract</p>
                                    <div className="card-actions justify-end">
                                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-error">
                                            Remove
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card my-2 mx-3 fade-in-left">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <div className="card-title text-primary">
                                        <a
                                            target="_blank"
                                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                        >
                                            Title
                                        </a>
                                        <svg
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                            x="0px"
                                            y="0px"
                                            width="20"
                                            height="20"
                                            viewBox="0 0 30 30"
                                            style={{ fill: "#F59E0B" }}
                                        >
                                            <path d="M 25.980469 2.9902344 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 25.869141 3 L 20 3 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 20 5 L 23.585938 5 L 13.292969 15.292969 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 14.707031 16.707031 L 25 6.4140625 L 25 10 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 27 10 L 27 4.1269531 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 25.980469 2.9902344 z M 6 7 C 4.9069372 7 4 7.9069372 4 9 L 4 24 C 4 25.093063 4.9069372 26 6 26 L 21 26 C 22.093063 26 23 25.093063 23 24 L 23 14 L 23 11.421875 L 21 13.421875 L 21 16 L 21 24 L 6 24 L 6 9 L 14 9 L 16 9 L 16.578125 9 L 18.578125 7 L 16 7 L 14 7 L 6 7 z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <p className="text-md">Abstract</p>
                                    <div className="card-actions justify-end">
                                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-error">
                                            Remove
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card my-2 mx-3 fade-in-left">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <div className="card-title text-primary">
                                        <a
                                            target="_blank"
                                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                        >
                                            Title
                                        </a>
                                        <svg
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                            x="0px"
                                            y="0px"
                                            width="20"
                                            height="20"
                                            viewBox="0 0 30 30"
                                            style={{ fill: "#F59E0B" }}
                                        >
                                            <path d="M 25.980469 2.9902344 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 25.869141 3 L 20 3 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 20 5 L 23.585938 5 L 13.292969 15.292969 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 14.707031 16.707031 L 25 6.4140625 L 25 10 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 1 0 27 10 L 27 4.1269531 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 25.980469 2.9902344 z M 6 7 C 4.9069372 7 4 7.9069372 4 9 L 4 24 C 4 25.093063 4.9069372 26 6 26 L 21 26 C 22.093063 26 23 25.093063 23 24 L 23 14 L 23 11.421875 L 21 13.421875 L 21 16 L 21 24 L 6 24 L 6 9 L 14 9 L 16 9 L 16.578125 9 L 18.578125 7 L 16 7 L 14 7 L 6 7 z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <p className="text-md">Abstract</p>
                                    <div className="card-actions justify-end">
                                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-error">
                                            Remove
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* Articles */}
                <div className="w-1/4 mt-4 mb-1 mx-4">
                    <CurrentACCI />
                </div>
            </div>
        </MainLayout>
    );
}
```

My code for "net_graph.tsx":

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "./net_graph.module.scss";


  

export function NetPlot(
  container:any,
  linksData:any,
  nodesData:any,
  nodeHoverTooltip:any

) {
  const links = linksData.map((d:any) => Object.assign({}, d));
  const nodes = nodesData.map((d:any) => Object.assign({}, d));

  const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  const height = containerRect.height;
  const width = containerRect.width;

  const color = () => { return "#9D79A0"; };

  const icon = (d:any) => {
    return d.gender === "male" ? "\uf222" : "\uf221";
  }

  const getClass = (d:any) => {
    return d.gender === "male" ? '.male' : '.female';
  };

  const drag = (simulation:any) => {
    const dragstarted = (event:any,d:any) => {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    };

    const dragged = (event:any,d:any) => {
      d.fx = event.x;
      d.fy = event.y;
    };

    const dragended = (event:any,d:any) => {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    };

    return d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended);
  };

  // Add the tooltip element to the graph
  const tooltip = document.querySelector("#graph-tooltip");
  if (!tooltip) {
    const tooltipDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tooltipDiv.classList.add('.tooltip');
    tooltipDiv.style.opacity = "0";
    tooltipDiv.id = "graph-tooltip";
    document.body.appendChild(tooltipDiv);
  }
  const div = d3.select("#graph-tooltip");

  const addTooltip = (hoverTooltip:any, d:any, x:any, y:any) => {
    div
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", 0.9);
    div
      .html(hoverTooltip(d))
      .style("left", `${x}px`)
      .style("top", `${y - 28}px`);
  };

  const removeTooltip = () => {
    div
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  };

  const simulation = d3
    .forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id((d:any) => d.id))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-150))
    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY());

  const svg = d3
    .select(container)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height]);
    // .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
    //   svg.attr("transform", event.transform);
    // }));

  const link = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#999")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .join("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", (d:any) => Math.sqrt(d.value));

  const node = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 12)
    .attr("fill", color);
    // .call((drag(simulation)));

  const label = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
    .attr("class", d => `fa ${getClass(d)}`)
    .text(d => {return icon(d);});
    // .call(drag(simulation));

  label.on("mouseover", (event,d) => {
    addTooltip(nodeHoverTooltip, d, event.pageX, event.pageY);
  })
    .on("mouseout", () => {
      removeTooltip();
    });

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    //update link positions
    link
      .attr("x1", (d:any) => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", (d:any) => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", (d:any) => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", (d:any) => d.target.y);

    // update node positions
    node
      .attr("cx", (d:any) => d.x)
      .attr("cy", (d:any)=> d.y);

    // update label positions
    label
      .attr("x", (d:any) => { return d.x; })
      .attr("y", (d:any) => { return d.y; })
  });

  return {
    
    destroy: () => {
      
      simulation.stop();
    },
    nodes: () => {
      return svg.node();
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `NetPlot` returns an object containing two `void` variables; to use a function as a JSX element it needs to return a `ReactNode`.

Remember, JSX is an abstraction of `React.createElement`.

Comment: I dont understand how to implement that, because I made a force graph using react.js and now I am using it on typescript, hence it is creating this error.
Now what should I change in order to return a react node?